# How to convert UTC time to user time zone?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-timepicker, android-date

I am getting UTC time from the server in `2021-06-20T09:56:05.697Z` format. I want to format it to user time zone and I tried the below code. But it returns

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-06-20T09:56:05.697Z"

Code used : (dateInString from server as "2021-06-20T09:56:05.697Z")

```
String dateStr = dateInString;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date dateex = df.parse(dateStr);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String formattedDate = df.format(dateex);
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Do you have further doubts or questions?

Answer (score 1):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Let’s first declare a formatter for the format we want:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now the conversion goes like this:

```
    String dateStr = "2021-06-20T09:56:05.697Z";

    Instant dateex = Instant.parse(dateStr);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = dateex.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String formattedDate = dateTime.format(FORMATTER);
    
    System.out.println("Formatted date and time: " + formattedDate);
```

Example output:

> Formatted date and time: 2021-06-20 05:56:05 AST

This was running on a computer in America/Tortola time zone, and we see that the date and time have been converted to Atlantic Standard Time as requested.

I am exploiting the fact that the string from the server is in ISO 8601 format, a format that the classes of java.time generally parse natively without any explicit formatter.

### What went wrong in your code?

When parsing the string from the server, if using a formatter for it, that formatter needs to know the format to be parsed. It doesn’t help that it knows the format to be formatted into later.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: I think you don't need to create a Formatter. I think there are already static ones you can use with the normal formats (I am not in front of android studio now, but I think it was `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` or similar, that has that particular format.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thank you for your comment. It depends on what you mean. For parsing the ISO format from the server we don’t need any formatter, and I am not creating any either. If we want output like `2021-06-20 05:56:05 AST`, then no provided formatter gives us that, which is why I created one for this purpose. Of course we might instead just print the `ZonedDateTime` without formatting it first, getting output like `2021-06-20T05:56:05.697-04:00[America/Tortola]`. Many users would not be quite happy …